# QnA Bot works when tested, but when embedded on a website always replies with "No Match Found!" unless an exact match

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

So I created a QnA bot using the Azure Portal and when I test the bot in the Azure Portal or embed the bot on a website and ask a variation of a question the bot should be able to answer, I receive the message "No Match Found!"

When I test the bot at the qnamaker.ai site and ask the exact same question, the bot works fine.

The odd thing is if I type the question **exactly** as it appears in my FAQ list, it works just fine and shows the correct response when tested on the azure portal, the web embed and the qnamaker.ai site.

I've trained and published the bot over and over to no avail. Am I missing something?

Following are screenshots of the various responses I get to the same question:

**This is the result of the test at the qnamaker.ai site. The response from the bot is the expected response:**

[image: Test at qnamaker.ai site]

**This is the result of the test at the Azure Portal site. The response from the bot is not right:**

[image: Azure Portal Test]

**This is the result of the bot being embedded in a site. The response from the bot is also not right:**

[image: Web embed test]

Can anyone please help? I'm losing my mind!

Comment: you may want to open a GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/new) for this.

Comment: I'm sure it's a daft question, but did you make sure to (re)train and (re)publish?

Comment: Of course @rposbo. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set subscription key and knowledgebaseID in azure portal under Application Setting.[image]